# How can I enable /dev/watchdog on Android when compiling from source?

Tags: android, linux, firmware, dragonboard

I'm trying to compile Android for the dragonboard 410, and would like to enable a firmware level functionality so my app can reboot the device if it crashes.

I noticed [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/watchdog/watchdog-api.txt) that the Linux source has exactly what I'm trying to implement.

I'm unfamiliar with compilation from source on Android, is there a compilation flag or option I can use to enable this functionality on Android?